# Default continue and if else statements

Tags: java

I'm using try on my code and it says illegal start of type. I'm using switch statements but default: continue; do not agree with each other I keep getting continue outside of loop. With the else statement it says illegal start type. So what can I do about try, continue, and the else statement.

```
   public class Menu {
private Inventory database;
private char menuItem;
private Scanner input;
private char mode;
int code;


public Menu(Inventory database)
{
    this.database = database;
    menuItem      = 'N';
    input = new Scanner(System.in);
}

public Menu(MyArrayList database)
{
    this.database = database;
    menuItem = 'A';
    input = new Scanner(System.in);

}

private void showMenu()
{
    if(code == 'A'){

    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("Display Movies : D");
     System.out.println("Add Movie      : A");
    System.out.println("Delete Movie   : X");
    System.out.println("Select Mode    : M");
    System.out.println("Exit           : E");
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please make your selection: ");

}
else    
{
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println("Display Movies : D");
    System.out.println("Rent a Movie   : R");
    System.out.println("Reserve a Movie: S");
     System.out.println("Select Mode   : M");
    System.out.println("Exit           : E");
    System.out.println("------------------");
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("Please make your selection: ");

}
}

private void rentMovie(int productID)
{
    int index = database.getIndex(productID);
    if( index == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("There is not such a code.");
    }
    else
    {
        if( database.getMovie(index).getIsRented())
        {
            System.out.println("You cannot rent " +  database.getMovie(index).getTitle() + ". It is already rented.");

        }
        else
        {
            database.getMovie(index).setIsRented(true);
            System.out.println("Please take your movie.");

        }
    }

}


private void reserveMovie(int productID)
{
    int index = database.getIndex(productID);
    if( index == -1)
    {
        System.out.println("There is not such a code.");
    }
    else
    {
        if( database.getMovie(index).getIsReserved() )
        {
            System.out.println("You cannot reserve " +  database.getMovie(index).getTitle() + ". It is already reserved.");
        }
        else
        {
            if( database.getMovie(index).getIsRented())
            {
                database.getMovie(index).setIsReserved(true);
                System.out.println( database.getMovie(index).getTitle() + " is reserved for you." );
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println( database.getMovie(index).getTitle() + " is available. You can rent it if you like.");
            }
        }
    }

}

try{
    if(mode == 'A'){
        switch(menuItem){
            case 'N':
                break;
            case 'D':
                database.print();
                showMenu();
                menuItem = input.next().charAt(0);
                break;
            case 'A':
                String title;
                System.out.println("Enter movie title, then press enter");//movie title,
                title= input.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Enter movie code, then press enter");//enter movie code,then press enter
                code = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
                addMovie(title,code);
                menuItem ='N';
                break;
            case 'X':
                System.out.println("");
                deleteMovie(code);
                menuItem ='N';
                break;
             case 'M':
                selectMode();
                menuItem = 'N';
             case 'E':
                System.out.print("Program terminated.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default:
                continue;
        }
    }
}
   else
{
    public void run(){
           int code;
    while(true)
    {

        switch(menuItem)
        {
            case 'N':
                break;
            case 'D':
                database.print();
                showMenu();
                menuItem = input.next().charAt(0);
                break;
            case 'R':
                System.out.print("Please enter product code:");
                rentMovie( input.nextInt() );
                showMenu();
                menuItem = input.next().charAt(0);
                break;
            case 'S':
                System.out.print("Please enter product code:");
                reserveMovie( input.nextInt() );
                showMenu();
                menuItem = input.next().charAt(0);
                break;
            case 'E':
                System.out.print("Program terminated.");
                System.exit(0);
                break;
            default :
                showMenu();
                menuItem = input.next().charAt(0);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Since you are new to java, what program are you using to edit your code?  Having an IDE will help you catch a lot of your syntax errors and help reformat all your indention. 

What is an IDE?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your edit, now showing the issue.
Your Try starts outside of a method body.

reserveMovie is closed just before try starts, and as such is not valid.

Comment: so I insert inside reserveMovie

Comment: You go back and study the code until you understand it. You Try shouldn't go anywhere as long as it doesn't have a catch

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You've got `else` following your `try` block, and that makes no sense.</strike> no, just bad indentation.

Where's your `catch` block, or `finally` block?  It makes no sense to just have `try`. Also, you can't just declare a function in the middle of that `else` block.

Basically, I recommend you re-study the "Java Syntax" chapter of whatever guide you're using, because this code is just all kinds of wrong.

Comment: Oh, well I don't have that. That's what I was thinking, "how is that there is try but no catch." I'm new at java so it gets confusing for me

Comment: Is a given assignment that our instructor gave us to add a switch statement

Answer (score 1):

A.. Few pointers..
First of all, your Try doesn't have a catch.
Your case statements lack {} blocks.
And you can't create a method within an else block.

Further to answer your Question: Illegal start of type means you haven't initiated the variable. For example "menuItem"

Edit: To further that, default should be break; not continue;

Edit2: And further your second switch contains a boolean as argument...